# DAPPER: Parameterized SQL search matching against multiple columns

Tags: dapper

Using Dapper and Oracle I want to give a query a list of tuples or three separate lists and generate a query that looks something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE (id,name,date)
IN ((1,'new','10-JUL-13'),(2, 'old','09-JUN-13'),(3,'ancient','08-JAN-87'))
```

Is there a way to format the query in C# to make this happen? Something like:

```
var query = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE (id,name,date) IN (:ids,:names,:dates)";
var result = connection.Query<MyClass>(query, new{ ids, names, dates });
```

Or:

```
var query = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE (id,name,date) IN (:myTuple)";
var result = connection.Query<MyClass>(query, new{ myTuple });
```

Comment: Interesting. Does oracle have any equivalent to table-valued-parameters?

Comment: It looks like it does. I'll see if going that route will work for me. Thanks @Marc. [link](http://appsjack.blogspot.co.uk/2010/09/pass-custom-udt-types-to-oracle-stored.html)

Comment: I haven't been able to get anything working using table value parameters. I tried installing this package https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper.Tvp/1.0.0 not sure if it supports oracle though.